# sudo: PERM_ROOT: setresuid(0, -1, -1): Operation not permitted

Tags: php, apache, exec, sudo

So the problem is that the error comes up in apache.err.

I CAN execute as the user in the shell.

```
root@ubuntu:~# su www-data
www-data@ubuntu:/root$ sudo /usr/local/bin/metronomectl restart
Stopped
Started
www-data@ubuntu:/root$
```

but when i try the same command through php

```
exec('sudo /usr/local/bin/metronomectl restart');
```

i get the error

```
sudo: PERM_ROOT: setresuid(0, -1, -1): Operation not permitted
```

user www-data IS in sudoers.

I'm at the end of my wits here... 
Any help is appreciated.

PS. Please ask if you need any extra info.

edit:

```
root@ubuntu:~# uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@ubuntu:~#
```

sudoers line:

```
www-data ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/metronomectl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by disabling mpm_itk module in apache.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of disabling mpm-itk outright, you could simply disable its limits on sudo:

```
<IfModule mpm_itk_module>
    # Permit using "sudo"                             
    LimitUIDRange 0 65534
    LimitGIDRange 0 65534
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Since mpm-itk has to be able to setuid(), it runs as root (although   restricted with POSIX capabilities and seccomp v2 where possible)

It looks like that seccomp v2 support (when on Linux 3.5.0 or newer) is completely breaks the execution of things like `sudo` or `crontab` since they use the `setuid` syscall internally.

A workaround is to not use `mpm_itk`, or avoid executing such binaries.

Refs: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=738131